# Custom URL rewrite, migrate one CMS to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cms-migration

I am trying to move my image gallery site from one CMS to Wordpress.
On current CMS I have page with medium size image on it with URL:

www.my-example-site.com/folder-one/subfolder-one/example-image-name.jpg.html

and another page with full resolution of same image on it with URL like this:

www.my-example-site.com/full-image/folder-one/subfolder-one/example-image-name.jpg-some-custom-keywords.html

I managed to make same address on test WP for medium size image, I created same categories with, and used same URL slug for categories.
After that, under settings --> permalinks I made custom URL structure like:

www.my-example-site.com/%category%/%postname%.jpg.html

and that made me the same urls for page with medium size image on it.

But, problem is with page with full size image on it.

Is there any way (some rewrite rule or something) to get another page to. It could be 301 redirect to something like this:

www.my-example-site.com/folder-one/subfolder-one/example-image-name.jpg.html?-some-custom-keywords.html

or anything similar, just to be able to use data as like on stardard page.

than I can use custom url check (on very top of single.php) to see if page contains "?-some-custom-keywords.html" to include file for generating that new page,
 if there is no that variable to include file for generating standard post page.

Please note that there are multiple different combination for "-custom-keywords.html" suffix (about 15)

If you have any question or suggestion please ask.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that these URL paths are stored in the database of your old CMS.
If so, you should be changing them there to match the standard URI of WordPress instead of rigging a way for the old paths to work.

Comment: Old CMS is file based system, it scans folders on disk and give URL of folder as it is on disk. I can use phpMyAdmin to search/replace in sql database, than to rename all folders on disk too. But, that will change just urls for medium size image not "/full-image/" urls. I managed to have same urls of normal page. I will try some plugins for WP with options to import list of all old urls and list of that urls on WP for 301 redirection. If you know some plugin which can do that, paste url. Or any other option you may have. Thanks.